# Integrity constraint violation 1062 duplicate entry - Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2.2, magento2.3.0

I'm facing this error in during when i run this setup:upgrade command. Can you help me regarding this issue, how to i'll fix this error ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your **eav_attribute_option_value** database table & set autoincrement sequencing to next increment number. And then do as what stated by Manish Chaubey.

> Remove duplicate primary key entry from table and then do setup upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Check your table which has duplicate entry and delete one.

Then run command `bin/magento setup:upgrade` .